# Batch Jobs Not Running When Set to Waiting on My Dev Server

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

My level of experience with the product is basic at best, but I'm expected to be a developer; I have a basic understanding of many things.

Right now my job is to investigate canceling lines in Purchase Orders. We have a workflow set up to handle those, and I'm trying to duplicate the scenario in my dev instance. Whenever a user cancels a line, the workflow is supposed to engage, and I've found that a batch job is what triggers that workflow to work (maybe that's the case with all workflows, but I don't know that for sure).

I've set up my personal Dev AX Instance under System Configuration => System => Server Configuration to use my personal Dev AOS server that my client is also running under, but when I go to System Configuration => Batch Jobs => Batch Jobs, then find the Batch Job I've been looking for and set the status to Waiting, the Batch Job *never* runs.

On our Test instance, the jobs is configured exactly the same way, except they use the AOS Server allotted for it. 
I did a SQL script to change the batch job to use my personal Dev AOS Server, then did a restart of the Dynamics AX Servers.

There must be something I'm doing wrong for my personal dev instance. I've been reading some things from here about what may be going on and following down the list, but I'm pretty sure the problem is even stupider => https://www.daxrunbase.com/2017/07/02/troubleshooting-batch-jobs-in-ax/

Comment: Under server config, there's a checkbox that you actually have to check to enable the server to be a batch server. Is that checked?

Comment: If you're talking about the AX Server Configuration Utility, I did not see an option for it, but if you're talking about System Administration => System => Server Configuration, yes it's checked.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the AOS? I've seen some weirdness happen with the clock, so it doesn't know it's time to start.

Comment: Yeah, I've restarted several times. I believe the AX server and computer's time are both using CST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, do you have all 3 workflow jobs set up?

- Workflow message processing
- Workflow due date processing
- Workflow line-item notifications

They can be set up from `System administration > Setup > Workflow > Workflow infrastructure configuration`.

Secondly, it is OK for the periodic batch jobs to have status `Waiting`. They will be in status `Executing` for a short time and then they will be `Waiting` for the next run. If the `Scheduled start date/time` value in this batch job is in the past, that could be a problem. Otherwise everything is OK.

Lastly, if you have already ticked the `Is batch server` check-box in `System administration > Setup > System > Server configuration`, please also make sure to move the workflow batch group in the `Batch server groups` section in the same form from `Remaining groups` to `Selected groups`.

The batch jobs should start at `Scheduled start date/time` - or a bit later, you'd need to wait a minute and refresh the grid.

Comment: I checked the Workflow Infrastructure Configuration Wizard, and see that all of those batch jobs are set to running by the time I reach the ending screen. From the Batch Job screen, the three batch jobs are set to Waiting status with a scheduled start time in the past, but the jobs never have an actual start time, which I interpret as "they have never run." The Is Batch Server field is checked. While I did not find a Remaining groups/Selected groups section in the Server Configuration, I did find that in System Configuration => Setup => Batch Group, but nothing seems to have worked.

Comment: You can check the batch group used by your batch jobs from the `Batch jobs` form > `View tasks` button. Is your server selected for this batch group in `System Configuration > Setup > Batch Group`?
If your batch jobs have status `Waiting` with a scheduled start time in the past then it is an issue. Can you check if there's any batch job with status `Executing` started a long time ago? It can be stuck and other batch jobs can be waiting for it to complete.

Comment: When I go to Batch Jobs and View Tasks on one of the workflow jobs, I see that it has a Batch Group of "System" and an AOS Instance Name of 01@MyDevServer. I don't know what the 01@ is for, but I assumed it was just a convention needed for the server. Should it just be MyDevServer?
01@MyDevServer is selected, and no other servers there.
I used SQL Script after a DB refresh maybe a month or three ago to change the statuses of all batch jobs to Withhold status. Over the last few days, I changed the statuses of the Workflow batch jobs by going to Batch Job => Functions, then selecting Waiting.

Comment: Have you checked if other batch jobs (not Workflow) can be run? If the problem is only with the Workflow batch jobs, you can cancel and delete them and then recreate from `System administration > Setup > Workflow > Workflow infrastructure configuration`.

Comment: Yes, I attempted to start some AIF batch jobs prior to the Workflow Configuration, but have met with similar results; they're in Waiting status, but there's never an Actual Start Time despite the Scheduled Start Time being in the past.

Comment: So none of your batch jobs start, not only the workflow. Just in case, what happens when you `Generate Full CIL` - you can find it in the Dev Workspace toolbar. Note: it can take some time (20 minutes) to run.

Comment: A full CIL? I'll do that and get back with you. BTW, thanks for being awesome on this!

Comment: The answer was not a Full CIL. Under the Server Configuration section, there's a section that allows you to indicate what batch groups the AOS should run. My AOS had an empty batch group selected; I set the AOS to use the Workflow batch group, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: That's what I meant by making sure to move the workflow batch group in the `Batch server groups` section from `Remaining groups` to `Selected groups`. It's good that you managed to resolve this.

Comment: Yeah, I had no idea that section existed, since when I opened up Server Configuration, the section was not in view. It was only after I maximized the menu that I found that section.